# Why my Android phone not correctly show a web page

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android, dolphin-browser

I can't show this [page](https://celcatfsi.ups-tlse.fr/FSIpargroupes/g771.html) using my Android device. I have used many browser but none of them show the timetable. I guess that my phone is missing something but what?

I'm using Android 2.3.7.

Comment: It looks like the timetable is inside an iframe element. Android has trouble with iframes, and the built-in browser [doesn't seem to support it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813301/iframe-on-android-browser-issue) at all.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger The problem is my version of android doesn't support xml-stylesheet. Opera mini support it.